# Is "into the house" an objective complement, or an adverbial phrase?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Spencer doesn't let the cat **into the house**.

Is "into the house" an objective complement, or an adverbial phrase?

Comment: I know this has been mentioned in comments before, but... If you're going to ask "terminology" questions like this, you really must *define your terms*, and explain why you're having difficulty assigning your example to one term or the other. Terminology in matters of grammar is notoriously variable, so we need to know what *you* understand by the alternatives. And if you don't actually *have* any possible terms, you might ask yourself what purpose is served by being given a name, if your real problem is that you don't understand the usage itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *objective complement* is a noun, adjective, or pronoun that qualifies the direct object of a verb; an example of *objective complement* is *governor* in "they elected him governor."

"Into the house" is an adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is an objective complement. I know that my position could be interpreted as a reformulation of grammar rules or grammatical analysis. But if we go beyond the structures, and we consider the real semantics of the structures involved, we can realize that into the house not only modifies the action of letting (actually, you perform an action like "letting "in a location, not towards a direction or location), but also the direct object. In a case like this, I prefer to analyze that "into the house is an adjectival or adjective phrase" functioning as an objective complement, as it happens not only with nouns ("they elected him governor"), boy also with adjectives ("they painted the house blue").